# setText is not able to change the text of my textView when used in start of the onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, oncreate, settext

setText is not able to change the text of my textView when used in start of the onCreate method, where as when i keep the setText at the end of Oncreate method then it is able to render the value to android UI.

I want to know why is it not able to render the value to UI when setText is being used in start

On keeping the timeView.setText(dateformatted); at the start of Oncreate method then in UI i am not able to see the time text value, 
where as On keeping the timeView.setText(dateformatted); at the end of Oncreate method i am able to see the time text value in the UI.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 TextView timeView =   findViewById(R.id.time);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateformatted = dateFormat.format(date);
        timeView.setText(dateformatted);
        Log.d( "Test00" ,dateformatted  );

// Whole rest of code, this way time text value does NOT show up in UI screen

} 


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Whole rest of code, this way time value does show up in UI screen

 TextView timeView =   findViewById(R.id.time);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dateformatted = dateFormat.format(date);
        timeView.setText(dateformatted);
        Log.d( "Test00" ,dateformatted  );
}
```

I was expecting the time value to be shown up in both cases, as no error, warning came up in the logs.

Comment: And you are not using timeView inside your [rest of code]??

Comment: @Naresh timeView is inside the [rest of code], in fact it is within the onCreate method itself, the only difference is i am using timeView.setText in starting of oncreate method and in other case at the end of oncreate method.

I was thinking is it due to that android is not able to identify so early, so no keeping it at end gives it some time to perform the activity of rendering the value to textView.

Comment: No there must be some other reason inside your rest of the code which may affect timeView directly or indirectly (by other views).
Can you post your layout and rest of the code??

Comment: well, i am not playing with timeView anywhere else in my code, initially it was a constant value manually given in xml page, but now i wanted to assign the current time dynamically, so doing it this way, its working though( on keeping it at end), But i was just curious to know why it did not work on keeping it in the starting.